# implementing OnItemClickListener, but onItemClick doesn't work

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick, focusable

In MainActivity there is onItemClick, and the activity iplements OnItemClickListener.
all is very simple, the result of this listener is to print with a Toas a message on screen when an user touch an item of the ListView.
But the onItemClick function doesn't work, why? [logCat without errors]
thanks in advance.

this is my main activity code:

```
package com.prendonota;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.prendonota.activeRecord.Nota;
import com.prendonota.crud.NotaCrud;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //*** identifico la ListView  che ho usato nell'xml
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaNote);

        //*** accedo al DB per prendere le note
        NotaCrud crud = new NotaCrud(this);
        List<Nota> listaNote = crud.getListNotes();

        //*** tramite il custom adapter inserisco ogni nota nel relativo item
        ListaNotaAdapter adattatore = new ListaNotaAdapter(this, R.layout.row, listaNote);

        //*** inserisco l'adapter personalizzato appena popolato nella ListView iniziale
        listView.setAdapter(adattatore);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void addNote(View view){
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "addNote()");
        Intent intent = new Intent( this, InsertNoteActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "onItemClick: +++ log +++");
        Toast.makeText( this, "Hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }


}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_nota"
        android:onClick="addNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/add_nota_label" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/add_nota" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my row.xml used for every item bt the adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



        <!--*** PARTE SUPERIORE ***-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_row_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFEC9">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_row_delete"
                android:onClick="crudClick"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon_delete"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_row_edit"
                android:onClick="crudClick"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_row_delete"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon_edit"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_data"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_row_edit"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <!--*** /PARTE SUPERIORE ***-->


        <!--*** PARTE INFERIORE ***-->
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/oggetto_row_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FCFBB5">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_oggetto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!--*** /PARTE INFERIORE ***-->



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your listview Xml

Comment: what contains your listview? which widgets?

Comment: i added the xml code in the original topic, thanks.

Comment: remove `android:focusable="true"` from your myrow.xml

Comment: done, but the result is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OnItemClick` method won't fire if the views in the list view are focusable.

Comment: i don't specify if focusable is true or false, simply the instruction in all my xml is not present...have i set it false?

Comment: some views are focusable by default - for example Button, ImageButton, etc...

Edit: now that I looked throught your xml - the issue is that you are using ImageButton. Set the listeners to each item separately in the getView method of the adapter instead of using `OnItemSelectedListener` or try setting focusable to false for the ImageButtons.

Comment: so if i use imageButton, there is nothing to do to use the listener on item?

Answer (score 3):

Making text selectable (`android:textIsSelectable`) allows the TextView to be focussed, and prevents any (short) click events getting to the `OnItemClickListener`.  `OnItemLongClickListener` will still work.

This represents a serious bug either in the Android libraries (if unintentional) or in the Android documentation (if intentional).  In any case, just change `android:textIsSelectable` to false and all will be well.

Comment: hi Canuck, i try your solution but nothing.
i have a row-layout(an item of list) with 2 textView and 2 imageButton...a try to set all views focusable:false and textIsSelectable:false...but nothig to do.
i'm using a ListFragment extension instead of ListActivity.

Comment: I deliberately chose ListActivity so that I'd have more control over the process, so, unfortunately, my experience is a bit different from yours.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late but, I had the same problem and solved by setting `onFocusable=false` programmatically, i.e., in my custom `ListViewAdapter`, on `getView(...)`, I retrieve the `ImageButton` calling `findViewById` and then change the focusable value by calling `setFocusable(false)` and `setFocusableInTouchMode(false)`:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alvappliances, parent, false);

    ImageButton delete = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.alvaDeleteIB);

    delete.setFocusable(false);
    delete.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me a bunch of time. Do you know why the xml is ignored?

Answer (score 1):

In your row.xml add following line in your Linear Layout tag

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to see if it helps

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```